# Why public and secret key isn't paired via key gen

Tags: linux, ssh

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048`

Then

`id_rsa`
`id_rsa.pub`
`known_hosts`

was generated

When I tried

`ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa`

Then

`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC84qa・・・Bgx`

When I opened `known_hosts` file. the `pub` key was displayed as following

`hikaru.com,172.14.240.3 ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDlHLh0bp・・・xeZx`

Why the pubkey is different between them ?

I understood that both of them shows `pub` keys.

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`known_hosts` shows the machine key of the remote box; even if you connected from `172.14.240.3` to `172.14.240.3` it wouldn't show you the key for your user account.